# Method to static method

Tags: php

Create class A has not method full

```
class A{

}
```

Create class B has method full

```
class B{
   public function full(){
      echo "success";
   }
}
```

How do?

```
A::full();
// success
```

Answer (score 1):

First class `A` should extend class `B` so the method `full` will available in class `A`.

```
class A extends B
{

}
```

Second you have to use `static` keyword in method `full`.

```
public static function full()
{
    ...
}
```

References :

[Inheritance](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php)

[Static](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

Comment: @BảoPhạmHoàng You cannot access non static method like this `A::full()`. You can create an instance of class `A` and call the method. `$a = new A(); $a->full()`

Comment: @BảoPhạmHoàng You can override method `full` in class `A`, but you cannot mark it as `static`.